# Call to undefined method Uni_Fileuploader_Helper_Data::getProductAttachments()

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am having the following error while trying to display product attachment:

```
Call to undefined method Uni_Fileuploader_Helper_Data::getProductAttachments() in www\app\design\frontend\my_theme\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 51
```

The way I'm calling the method is:

```
<?php $attachments = Mage::helper('fileuploader')->getProductAttachments($_product->getId(), 1);
if (count($attachments) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach ($attachments as $_attachment): ?>
        <?php echo $_attachment['file']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that function is not located in the class you're instantiating in your code. Upon further inspection on the module's code, that function is defined in 
    Uni_Fileuploader_Block_Fileuploader
So what you need to do is declare your block as

```
 <block type="fileuploader/fileuploader" name="product.attachments" template="fileuploader/attachments.phtml"/>
```

Then you can access that function through $this, like so

```
$this->getProductAttachments()
```

As an alternative, you can go to Uni_Fileuploader_Helper_Data and copy the function from  Uni_Fileuploader_Block_Fileuploader, since you can't change the template type on a core template without breaking the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm calling this in catalog/product/list.phtml. Any idea where should I declare it. I've tried catalog.xml but it did not help. Thanks

Comment: Oh I see, just go to app/code/community/Uni/Fileuploader/Helper/Data.php and copy the function you want from app/code/community/Uni/Fileuploader/Block/Fileuploader

Comment: Thanks mate. I found it before your answer but still that was the fix.